# Reduce space between logo and the element below it

Tags: html, css

So, I am building this website for my class and the professor suggested that I should place my logo on the top left corner of my website. Some has kindly helped me place the logo but the space below the logo and just above the hero banner is too big, I have tried to reduce the space by using the padding in CSS but it did not work.

This is the current coding for the header:

```
<header role="banner" id="home" class="site-header">
<div class="container container--max">
  <h1 class="site-header__title">
    <a href="#home"><img src="images/logo2.png"></a>
  </h1> <!-- end .site-header__title -->
```

And this is my website: http://gabrielr.sgedu.site/final-project Any tips/help?

Answer (score 1):

Your logo is nested in an `h1` element, which normally comes with top and bottom margin space.

[image]

You can control the distance of the logo from the hero image by adjusting the margins on the `h1`.

Start with this:

```
header > .container > h1 { margin: 0; }
```

This looks good:

```
header > .container > h1 { margin: .5em 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

**Set required margin** in below class

```
.site-header__title
{
  margin:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers above are already good, so just for your reference...

If you're using Firefox or Chrome, you can press F12 and bring up the developer console; from there it is easy to play around with formatting in CSS and figure out what CSS changes you'd like before going and changing in your editor and uploading.

As in, you can easily see what the container boxes look like, where spacing in margins and padding is coming from; and also test out different values in browser to iron out what it's going to look like before committing to your editor and FTP.

I find this process is a much faster why of ironing out display bugs and layout issues.

If you find it useful and you start to get into Javascript/jQuery, consider the Firebug plugin which makes debugging AJAX also so much easier. You can also all of the regular CSS manipulations in browser.

Give that that work flow a try; I personally find it much faster. Good luck!

Comment: I just did this for another modification and it was so helpful. Thank you so much for your insights!

Comment: Fantastic :-) Glad it helps... I do so much CSS in browser these days! If Firefox you can also copy/paste your CSS code from the developer Window straight into your HTML / CSS editor.

Comment: Also considering using a CSS reset script:

    http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Something like this will give you a level playing field, so you specify all your own paddings and margins. The idea is to have everything zero'd so that the end result is the same across all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Add `height` to your `.site_header` and this reduces you spacing below logo and above video.

```
.site-header {
  height:85px;
  background: #29272C;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! :) This is actually extremely helpful!

Comment: Welcome @GabiRodríguez, If it worked then do accept the answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can add the top padding for `.site-header__title`:

```
eg.site-header__title { padding: 5px 0 0 0; }
```

Or you can set the height of `.site-header class`.